# Calculating taxes with paypal standard add button

Tags: paypal

someone could help me to configure a % of taxes regarding to the customer's country? How have I to set the variable? In my paypal business account (italian) there is'nt a particular section in which do that, so I'll have to edit the code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get a HTML block to paste on your website? If so, could you please add it to your question?

When i coded such a form myself i just added this line my form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="tax_rate" value="25">
```

This ads a 25% tax to your product at check out. So if the price without tax is 10$ then at checkout the product will cost 10$+2.5$ tax. so 12.5 total.